# ¿Cómo controlar un error con una excepción?

Tags: excepciones, recursión, numberformat

Estoy haciendo un método recursivo que informe si un número es un número de Mágico (suma de 2 números al cubo). ¿Cómo puedo controlar este error con una excepción cuando salta de esta forma?:

Aquí el código de la clase.

```
  public static boolean Recursivo_esH(int num, int i, int j){

 if(j>=num) { return false; }

 if(i>=num){
     return false;
 }

 double numero1,numero2;

 numero1= Math.pow(i, 3);
 numero2= Math.pow(j, 3);

 if(numero1+numero2==num){
 return true;
 }
 else {

     return Recursivo_esH(num,i,j+1);
     }

    }
```

Estos son los parametros que estoy enviando desde el "main":

```
  public static void main(String []args) throws noEs_HardyException{

boolean vigia = false;

vigia= (Recursivo_esH(56453,1,1));      

if(vigia==true) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El numero es H");

}
else {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El numero NO Es H");

}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error se produce porque se llama demasiadas veces la función recursiva y eso produce el `StackOverflowError`.

La solución a eso sería acotar los valores máximos de i y j para que no sean mayores que la raíz cúbica del número que se está comprobando:

```
public static boolean Recursivo_esHardyRamanujan(int num, int i, int j) {



        if (j >= Math.cbrt(num)) {
            j = 0;
            i++;

        }
        if (i >= Math.cbrt(num)) {
            return false;
        }

        double numero1, numero2;

        numero1 = Math.pow(i, 3);
        numero2 = Math.pow(j, 3);


        if (numero1 + numero2 == num) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return Recursivo_esHardyRamanujan(num, i, j + 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: De nuevo, Gracias!